# Building whistling muscles

Tags: voice

I happen to inherit the ability of emotionally creative whistling to good music. To prove my point, here's a piece to which I whistle:
https://app.box.com/s/grkromn1brjksou5qecwgs9w6odwi7ik
My problem: When I was younger, I whistled up to 13 hours non-stop, but now that I stopped for many years (and at 77), I'm only able to whistling about 5 minutes strong enough and then I feel that I'm losing muscle strength.
I guess physio therapists know how to go about to regain muscle strength. My reasoning leads me to gradually build up my whistling muscles, such as whistling only for 5 minutes daily 3-5 times for about 2 weeks and then increase the time to 10 for another 3 weeks etc. 
Yesterday I started and straight away felt my muscle signaling some changes. I wonder if taking Collagen or other muscle building supplements might be helpful?
I would be grateful for some professional advice, because here we have got an orchestra, which would like to have me perform.

Comment: Wow! My first thought was that man people claim they can whistle and many can't. But man – you can! I really like your whistling! Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

@DrSvanHay has convinced me to open an unknown executable archive on a note that looks like (not that I thought it was) a hustle...

77yo and how many months? ;-)

I'm a pro whistler looking for people/places to jam with same as yourselves (R and L brain and diaphragm-gangliation), even on the phone (POTS!) if necessary.

I hope you'll think twice about your schedule. Even with good THC and focus, I would say "weeks" should have been "days" (although the schedule for each day sounds rightish) I don't know your hormonal regime and I'm looking into building muscle with chemical aid (pre-60s) myself, but generally, I'd say one really needs to push for longer by 20 secs every other session, until you get so much burn that you need to skip two full sessions. The focus is to feel each little twinge of distress with, differentiating from true stop-now WARNING alerts, by pushing very hard and then overdoing by a bit just as hard but very slowly/slightly.
If you really had to skip a full additional day or two, beyond 1, well THEN I'd drop back most of a minute, and start adding 3 secs per session again next time, possibly now only every two sessions (sets, in muscle-building speak).

You need to get intimate with "pleasurably-quite-sore" and know how long it will "almost kill" after a workout to make your jowlage (tongue too? I'll have to hear your styles) and lippage grow musclebulk fastest.

I've only ever done this on legs, so I don't know how sore would even feel, cheekwise. I whistle for 2-5 hours maybe, without tiring, but I'll vary my genres/dynamics and never did it as a career quite yet.

I heard 2009-era advise or read in a mag thenabouts, that very-precise (like... 20-35 mins before or rather, I'm remembering now... after??) timed-intake of your tunafish or proteinshake or proteingoopack or whatever, is key. Some paper showing high-pro-level bodybuilders who ate their protein exactly-ish (w/in 10mins or so of "optimal" which was, I think 25-35 minutes after last weightlift that day, bulked in the critical pre-tournament penultimate week(s?) by 20% or some such hugely advantageous amount, faster, than their competitors who missed the protein-reuptake ingestion target by not much more... like "anything more than 30 mins").

If I were/am(?) you, I'd read up on the research... been years since the Gym, so I'm ready to listen if you look it up, too). It's supposed to hurt every time, and for big muscles, they only generally recommended one work half one's body's groups each day, with the half off rotation being the one hard at work building muscle-fiber by/while repairing the microtears that help make way for more. So, yeah, on seccond-thought, I'd definitely work to the slightest bit beyond exhaustion ("that last forced half-rep") on the last time each day, and skip the next day, for at least a fortnight, before trying any every-day testing... we'll have to do our own research on whistle-muscles, no doubt, but what works for other muscles is the thing I'd try first.

Can't wait to hear your file! Cheers! Thanks for inspiring me to start excercising, today, for real!

Let me know if you have/recommend BandCamp or SoundCloud, and I'll sign up and meet you there. (Or wherever there's a similar site with a record-together-online function added to it?)